What size wire would I use with a 115v submersible well pump at 100 feet?
What size wire would I use with a 115v submersible well pump at 100 feet?
My well is 80 feet deep. The well is 20 feet from the house.
I want to use a 115v pump.
What gauge wire can I use? Can I get away with #14?

#14 is only allowed on 15 amp breakers.  At 100 feet 14 might do, but a case can be made for 12 gauge also.

Why shoot yourself in the foot with a 120VAC pump? In any case, not enough information given - WHICH 120V pump determines what wire you need (there's very likely a chart in the pump's installation manual, even.) The same pump in 240V configuration can use smaller wire.

This right here is why we use 240V pumps for wells.  180’ run is no big deal at 240V.   I take it your aspiration is to keep it alive on a 120V generator or inverter?  What are the running amps of the pump?

We need to know the current draw or horsepower of the pump. The length of the run is normally only important if it exceeds 100 feet. If it can be wired for 240 that would be the preferred method. As Harper said though, we need to know the current draw of the pump you intend to use.
